# Maximal normal $2$-subgroup of $D_{20}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to find maximal normal $2$-subgroup of the  dihedral group $D_{20}$, of order $40.$ According to me as Sylow $2$-subgroups are isomorphic to $D_4$, are $5$ in numbers so not normal. Center of group is $C_2$ i.e. cyclic group of order $2$ is normal. There are  also subgroups of order $4$, $C_4$  and $C_2\times C_2$ but i do not know that these are normal or not. Please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, the maximum normal  2-subgroup has order 4, not 2. Secondly, the group $D_{20}$ has subgroups of order $2$ that are not normal. And thirdly, the maximal normal $2$-subgroup of any finite group is unique, so there can only be one answer, not several.

Comment: @DerekHolt  thanks ......can you please tell me which subgroup is maximal normal $2$-subgroup.

Comment: Here $D_{20}$, is of order $40.$

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you tell me which subgroup is that one....

Comment: I think $C_4$ is the required one ?

Comment: Yes that's right, it's the subgroup of order $4$ in the rotation subgroup.